# Run Kruskal-Wallis (and Dunn's Test) with multiple responses in R

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

I want to compare three groups with each other and have chosen the Kruskal-Wallis test and then the Dunn's test as post-hoc test.

If I have a data set like this:

```
df <- data.frame (group  = c("Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","Trtm1","Trtm1","Trtm1","Trtm2","Trtm2","Trtm2","Ctrl","Ctrl","Ctrl","Trtm1","Trtm1","Trtm1","Trtm2","Trtm2","Trtm2"),
                  height = c(5,4.5,5.5,10,10.5,9.5,1,0.5,0.25,5,4.5,5.5,10,10.5,9.5,1,0.5,0.25),
                  weight = c(20,21,19,45,40,42,5,4,3,20,21,19,45,40,42,5,4,3)
)
```

With three groups and two responses to the treatments I would run Kruskal-Wallis test and then Dunn's test to find out if there is a difference between the treatments.

```
library(dunn.test)
kruskal <- kruskal.test(df$weight, df$group)
ph <- dunn.test(df$weight, df$group, method = "bonferroni")
```

So far so good; however, if I want to find out if there is a difference for the second response, too, doing the same test again for the second response like this:

```
kruskal <- kruskal.test(df$height, df$group)
ph <- dunn.test(df$height, df$group, method = "bonferroni")
```

feels like multiple testing. So I wanted to include both responses in one test. From the documentary I understood, that it was possible to include a list of vectors in the tests.

However this

```
kruskal <- kruskal.test(list(df$height,df$weight), df$group)
ph <- dunn.test(list(df$height,df$weight), df$group, method = "bonferroni")
```

does not work. Any ideas how I could use the Kruskal-Wallis test and the Dunn's test with multiple responses?

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: The aim makes no sense that I can see. Kruskal-Wallis is for a single outcome variable and two or more groups. If you want to compare  height and weight combinations you need something else, perhaps MANOVA. (At first glance this seemed off-topic as a request for code, but the real question is about statistical goals.)

Comment: What is "the documentary"?